# problems using GLM

Tags: machine-learning, glm, statsmodels

I have some difficulties understanding how to use GLM model with poisson.

```
import numpy as np
import scikits.statsmodels as sm

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(100)*1000, 
                        'B':np.random.rand(100)*100,  
                        'C':np.random.rand(100)*10, 
                        'target':np.random.rand(100)})

X = dataset.ix[:,['A','B','C']].values
y = dataset.ix[:,['target']].values
size = 1e5
nbeta = 3

fam = sm.families.Poisson()
glm = sm.GLM(y,X, family=fam)
res = glm.fit()
```

- I am using "target" column as a target, Should I label the target to O or 1 ?
- Can anyone explain how ca I get the predicted value as poisson has another function [predict](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Poisson.html?highlight=family.poisson#statsmodels.genmod.families.family.Poisson)

Comment: This is a very, very old version of statsmodels if you are importing from the scikits namespace. You should definitely upgrade.

Comment: Can you show an example with the upgraded version ? Can I find this GLM on scikit, I coudln't find it

Comment: Poisson models are intended for count data models (unless you know what you're doing and are purposefully applying them to continuous data). Are you sure you want to use Poisson here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sourceforge is down right now. When it's back up, you should read through the [documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/) and [examples](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/). There are plenty of usage notes for prediction and GLM.

How to label your target is up to you and probably a question for cross-validated. Poisson is intended for counts but can be used on continuous data, but you should know what you're doing.

If you have 0/1 then you want a Logit or Probit model. Something like this. You don't need to convert the pandas objects to numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(100)*1000, 
                        'B':np.random.rand(100)*100,  
                        'C':np.random.rand(100)*10, 
                        'target':np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)})

X = dataset[['A','B','C']]
X['constant'] = 1
y = dataset['target']
size = 1e5
nbeta = 3

fam = sm.families.Poisson()
glm = sm.GLM(y,X, family=fam)
res = glm.fit()

predict = res.predict()
```

Or you could directly use the maximum likelihood estimator for Poisson.

```
res = sm.Poisson(y, X).fit()
predict = res.predict()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Just wondering if we can use time-series with this example to predict next event (based on time). let's cosider :  'B': np.array([datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 28, i, 0) for i in range(30)])

Comment: As far as implementation, datetime should behave like an integer under the hood, so in principle it could work. As far as, is this what you want to be doing...that's a question for cross-validated. You may be able to model a Poisson process like this, but you might want to look into survival analysis. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44046/what-are-the-differences-between-survival-analysis-and-poisson-regression) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! if I understand you well. If I wanna predict the probability of occurrence based on the level of the predictor then I'll use Binomial GLM. If I want to predict the number of events based on the predictor level then you would use the Poisson GLM. I see that "res.predict()" produce probabilities, what does these probabilities mean in this case. if it's predicting the number of events (numbers varies from one to others.). One more question, should we label the target in (O or 1) as we do with logistic regression ?

Comment: Yes that's right for Binomial and Poisson. The `predict` method depends on the family used. For Binomial, it can be interpreted as probabilities. For Poisson, it can be interpreted as expected counts. Whether you want to label the target 0 or 1 is up to you (and, again, a question for cross-validated), but, yes, GLM with Binomial is analogous to logistic regression. In the case of Poisson, you *can* use continuous response variable, but you should look into what this means for the model.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers :)

Comment: I am trying to measure the prediction accuracy of GLM. But unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to do that. When I use sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y, predict). I get an error, How can I measure the accuracy of predicted values in GLM. (Predict val in this case). I'm getting this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288718/convert-numpy-ndarray-to-pandas-serie

Comment: I could add some code to GLM for this. You can do the following from `np.histogram2d(actual, (predicted > .5), bins=2)[0]` https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py#L2465

Comment: @jseabold, could you please comment is it correct to use GLM without split data to train/ test?